# Using forms in facebook apps in PHP

Tags: php, facebook, forms

I'm trying to use a standard form in a facebook application

the form code look like this

```
<form method="POST" action="/bristolhouse/">
<input type="hidden" name="kind" value="admin" />

{$admin_message} <br />

<input type="submit" value="Add" />
</form>
```

The error I'm getting is

API Error Code: 100
API Error Description: Invalid parameter
Error Message: Requires valid redirect URI.

I've seen this error before when I didn't have the correct values in my config file for the redirect URI. I'm not sure if i need to include auth_tokens or how I should be including the URI. I can't find any examples on the net.

Edit: For example the link I'm getting to is https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=282683341837527&redirect_uri=

so I'm getting to the right place just not passing the correct parameter

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion, try changing `action="/bristolhouse/"` to `action="bristolhouse"`

ie removing the slashes

Comment: the form it submitting to the right place it's just not submitting the right info.

Comment: That's not what your question states? Be specific. Also "Error Message: Requires valid redirect URI" implies you do have a problem with the URI..

Comment: I was being specific, the form is loading the correct page but it's not passing the redirect URI. I can't find the way that facebook expects this to be done.  I'd added stuff to my original explanation to show what I mean